# Kendo DateTimePicker set min value will change the time options

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

This is an runnable code demonstrate the problem: http://dojo.telerik.com/obATO

Here is the same code in case the link is broken:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datetimepicker/index">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.flat.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.flat.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

        <div id="example">
            
            <div class="demo-section k-content">
                <h4>Remind me on</h4>
                <input id="datetimepicker" style="width: 100%;" />
            </div>
            
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    // create DateTimePicker from input HTML element
                    $("#datetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
                        value:new Date()
                    });
                  
                    $("#datetimepicker").data("kendoDateTimePicker").min(new Date(2016, 8, 28, 11,29));
                });
            </script>
            
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a Kendo DateTimePicker, which I do not set the interval explicitly so by default the time options will be of 30 minutes interval, eg: 00:00, 00:30 ... 23:30

Now I want to set the minimum value of the control as some strange DateTime, in my code example I set it to "2016-09-28 11:29:00", so that I expect two things would happen:

1. When user input DateTime smaller than this value, the control will auto set to this value as it is minimum value
2. The time option in the drop down list of TimePicker will only show options larger to this value PLUS the minimum value itself, so should be like 11:29, 11:30, 12:00, 12:30...23:30

While the first thing is achieved, the second point doesn't.  The time options become 11:29, 11:59, 12:29...23:29, 23:30.

So my question is, is this normal? and how can I achieve the second point mentioned above?

(It is acceptable that the minimum value itself does not appear in the options, but I want the options stay the same instead of shifting due to the minimum value set)

Comment: this question might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630096/kendo-ui-timepicker-custom-interval-format

Answer (score 0):

I had the same behavior today..
In my case, I rounded the time.

Something like this:

```
var dateMin = new Date(2016, 8, 28, 11,29);
dateMin.setHours(dateMin.getHours() + Math.round(dateMin.getMinutes() / 60));
dateMin.setMinutes(0);

$("#datetimepicker").data("kendoDateTimePicker").min(dateMin);
```

Comment: I don't think this answer my problem, as I have cases that need to intentionally setting the min value to non-rounded value like 15:02, 18:23, etc....

Answer (score 0):

I have submitted a Telerik support ticket, and here is their reply:

> By default, the min value will specify the starting point of the interval in the timeview. You have two options for handling this behavior:
>
> 1. Set the min value to be a value from the list (intervals in the time view): min: new Date(2016, 8, 28, 11,00)
> 2. Define the dates collection for the particular min date:
>
> http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datetimepicker#configuration-dates
>
> However, the second approach will require the re-initialization of the
> widget through its setOptions method and I would personally recommend
> to use the first approach, where you need to set the time of the min
> value to match one of the values in the interval.

In short: this is the expected behavior and there is no "fast" workaround.